# How can I make this "Pick" inside a "Table" run faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, coding-style

I am working on becoming more and more familiar with MMA and on a scale from one to ten, I would rate myself as a four or a five. I understand vectorization and that loops-are-very-bad. I have recently learned anonymous functions and mapping in MMA. I have yet to understand patterns and associations so I am avoiding them for right now.

This is my first non-trivial program in MMA. I have optimized it as much as I can. But I would like to see if it can be made even faster.

The problem description is that I have some particles and some measurements associated with them. The particles occupy integer coordinates. The occupied coordinates can have one or more particles. I want to specify a threshold and then pick coordinates which have more than the threshold number of particles and then export them to a text file.

- The main goal here is time efficiency. Can this code be made faster? I don't care about memory efficiency.
- I am using as many existing functions as I could find. Are there any others that I missed?
- The actual problem is much larger and is repeated many times. `data` contains about 50,000 particles. `threshold` is at ten. Out of those 50,000 `xyzCoordinates`, only 1500 coordinates are exported, which corresponds to about half (25,000) of the particles.
- I am trying to learn good MMA coding habits. Any general comments on my style/formatting are also welcome.
- The exporting to a text file is being done simply because sometimes I just want to open up a file and see the particle data. It is not super important so I am willing to be convinced if someone makes a good argument against it. Maybe there is another exporting command/formatting which is much faster? Like the `.mat` files in `MATLAB`?
- No matter what the format, the exporting has to be done though, because I have to post-process the separated particles. Profiling tells me that exporting to CSV accounts for about 25% of the time. The rest of it is taken up by the `Take` command inside the `Table`. The rest of the code is negligible but if it can be improved in anyway, I will love to learn.

Here is the explanation of the code with a complete minimum working example underneath it.

```
In[1]:= (*Seeding the RNG for consistency.*)
SeedRandom[1234];

In[2]:= (*Creating fake data with a hundred rows and seven columns. \
Each row represents measurements for a particle so there a hundred \
particles here.*)
data = RandomReal[1, {100, 7}];

In[3]:= (*These are the (x,y,z) coordinates for each of the hundred \
particles. The coordinates are always positive integers, on a bounded \
integer lattice. In this case, x, y, and z each take values from \
{1,2,3}. Coordinates can have any number of particles, one or more.*)


xyzCoordinates = RandomInteger[3, {100, 3}];

In[4]:= (*Now we tally the xyzCoordinates to count how many particles \
are there at each coordinate.*)
Take[Tally@xyzCoordinates, 10]

Out[4]= {{{0, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2, 0, 1}, 2}, {{0, 1, 2}, 1}, {{2, 0, 2}, 
  4}, {{0, 0, 2}, 3}, {{2, 2, 3}, 6}, {{2, 3, 2}, 4}, {{1, 2, 0}, 
  1}, {{3, 1, 2}, 3}, {{0, 3, 1}, 5}}

In[5]:= (*We define a threshold here. This will be a small integer, \
let's say between one and ten.*)
threshold = 2;

In[6]:= (*Now we select the xyzCoodinates which have more than \
threshold=2 particles.*)
coordinatesToExport = 
 Select[Tally@xyzCoordinates, #[[2]] > threshold &][[All, 1]]

Out[6]= {{2, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 2}, {0, 3,
   1}, {1, 3, 2}, {0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {3, 3, 3}, {2, 0, 3}, {1, 3, 
  0}, {2, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}

In[7]:= (*Now we know how which xyzCoordinates have more than \
threshold=2 particles. For each of those selected coordinates, we \
select the corresponding rows from data and export to a text file. I \
have commented out the Export command but if you uncomment it, you \
will end up with fourteen small textfiles in the same directory as \
this notebook, each containing some number of particles' data.*)
Table[
  dataToWrite = 
    Pick[data, (# == coordinatesToExport[[fileNameIndex]]) & /@ 
      xyzCoordinates];
  (*outputFile=NotebookDirectory[]<>ToString[fileNameIndex]<>".txt";
  Export[outputFile,dataToWrite,"CSV"];*),
  {fileNameIndex, 1, Length[coordinatesToExport], 1}];

In[8]:= (*Here is the complete MINIMUM WORKING EXAMPLE*)
SeedRandom[1234];
data = RandomReal[1, {100, 7}];
xyzCoordinates = RandomInteger[3, {100, 3}];
threshold = 2;
coordinatesToExport = 
  Select[Tally@xyzCoordinates, #[[2]] > threshold &][[All, 1]];
Table[
  dataToWrite = 
    Pick[data, (# == coordinatesToExport[[fileNameIndex]]) & /@ 
      xyzCoordinates];
  (*outputFile=NotebookDirectory[]<>ToString[fileNameIndex]<>".txt";
  Export[outputFile,dataToWrite,"CSV"];*),
  {fileNameIndex, 1, Length[coordinatesToExport], 1}];
```

Comment: `Pick[data, xyzCoordinates, Alternatives @@ coordinatesToExport]` will generate the data to write in one go, s/b order or two magnitude faster. In any case, the writing of data will likely swamp any internal speedup.